# Using a replacement AC-AC adapter that has a lower current specification

Tags: power-supply

There are many similar questions for AC-DC adapters but couldn't find an answer for the AC-AC adapters, I apologize if it has been already replied but I have missed it.

I have bought an old headphone amp that requires a 16VAC adapter. Another specification is that it should supply 1000mA current. I have searched all the online retailers in the country that I live and the best I have found was an adapter that is rated for 600mA. The headphone amp has five outputs, so I thought if I don't use all the outputs with full power 600mA will be sufficient, is this correct? I also thought that since this is an AC adapter it possibly only uses a transformer and the current limitation is only relevant when there is a risk of overheating, so if I choose to not to use all the outputs with full power it should be okay. What do you think?

Best regards.

Comment: I think it has a good chance of working, but you should watch out for overheating to be sure.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Transformer-1000mA-Straight-Female/dp/B00B8865BG

Comment: Thanks but I am living in Czech Republic and this is what I found: https://www.amazon.de/Rockpower-Netzteil-Adapter-16V-600/dp/B00EA192PO/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1536283465&sr=8-3&keywords=16vac

Comment: Are you sure it's 16VAC and not 16VDC ? it's quite an unusual input. What is the product reference?

Comment: Are you sure it's 16VAC and not 16VDC ? it's quite an unusual input. What is the product reference?

Comment: The product is the first version of Presonus HP4. In later versions they have switched to 12VDC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have no choice but to use what you can get, as long as you watch out for over heating of the transformer. If it is HOT to the touch, it is over loaded.

Another option is to buy 2 of them and wire the 16 VAC wires in parallel. Be sure they are in phase so you get 16 VAC at about 1200 mA of current. That should be plenty enough to run all outputs at full power. Also make sure they plug into the same AC outlet so they are in phase.

Comment: That's a good solution from a technical point of view on the other hand eventually I will pay more for two transformers than the intricate headphone amp.